# How to print variable as constant in PHP?

Tags: php

I know this is stupid but here it is,

How do I do this

```
echo "Hi my name is $name";
```

to print as

```
Hi my name is $name
```

Comment: You could escape the `$` character with a backslash `\\` or use single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Use `''` instead of `""`

```
echo 'Hi my name is $name';
```